# Autorefresh for Postgres materialised view?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

Is it possible to set an automatic refresh frequency for materialized views?

Here's the situation, I have an important but relatively small (20 thousand row) table that's subject to constant updates (hundreds of updates/second). The table is also subject to frequent (low priority) reads. What I've done before is to copy the table every 60 seconds into a second table and allow public read-only access to that table.

I suspect that using a materialized view is a more suitable solution, but if possible I'd also like to automatically refresh the view based on the number of SELECTs made against the view. If no-one SELECTS from the view the don't bother with a refresh, but if the view is being accessed then the table should be refreshed every 60 seconds.

Is this something that postgres provides a solution to, or should I code the refreshing of the view into my application?

Comment: check this answer please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906977/refresh-a-materialized-view-automatically-using-a-rule-or-notify